# Insert my assigned word by key in Notepad++

Tags: binding, notepad++

Is it possible to bind a key to insert a specific word in Notepad++?

*For example:*
When pressing the `F11` key, the word `Day` was inserted in the editor.

Or somehow make an additional menu in the editor, where I can enter the word `Day` and copy from there if necessary.

Comment: Type the word `Day` somewhere in your text, then `Ctrl + X` the then `Ctrl + V` in every places you want. Or may be it's an XY problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @ Toto Then will have to constantly enter the word `Day` somewhere. I want the word to be in the additional menu and to be stored there even after the editor has been closed. Or it could be inserted using the hotkeys.

Comment: I have the asnwer for this but is not a very "straight forwad" solution... it wil post it anyways coz the solution am offering is pretty cool

Comment: @ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ What is the solution? Can you share?